# What is this white part of these lamb chops called?

Tags: lamb, fat

What is the white part (circled in black) of these lamb chops called?  I know they contain fat, but is there a name for the tissue itself?  Do they occur throughout the meat or is it only in certain parts?  I believe back lamb racks don't contain them, but the front ones do.  Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: Maybe lamb fat (suet)?

Comment: I don't think this is what is making you dizzy. Perhaps something else you are having with the dinner? Or maybe a blood sugar issue? There is just no realistic reason why the sinew/fat of a piece of meat would suddenly make you lightheaded. (please consult your primary physician)

Comment: @roetnig i thought suet was particularly the fat from around the kidney?

Comment: @RobinBetts suet is located also in the loins and other parts

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from your photo, but probably fat or connective tissue.